# Is there any example of a Turing-recognizable language mapping reducible to a NOT Turing-recognizable language?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-recognizable

Theorem: "If A is mapping reducible to B and B is recognizable, then A is recognizable."

I know that the following statement is FALSE.

"If A is mapping reducible to B and A is recognizable, then B is recognizable."

But I can't come up with an example to prove that.

Comment: You can map all recognizable problems to an instance of "does this program accept all inputs?", which isn't recognizable.

Answer (score 1):

Assume we have alphabet $\{0,1\}$.
Map string $w$ to $0{\cdot} w$. Then a copy of $A$ is found in $B$ as all strings starting with $0$. The strings in $B$ that start with $1$ can have any property you like.